# Can I set certain choices on a picklist as unavailable to users, but available to approval process field updates?

Tags: approval-process

Basically, I want the user to be able to select 'Preparing for Submission' or 'Ready to Submit', but I only want the approval process to be able to select 'Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3', 'Approved'. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, with Record Types (see https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm for details.) You could have one Record Type "In Approval" with all of the options with a different one for the users. Workflows or triggers could automatically switch the Record Type as necessary.

Comment: This makes sense, but once the workflow updates the record type, any users that have the ability to edit the record during the approval process (which is necessary for the process) would still be able to edit the status field, right? Is it possible to lock that specific field while the process is underway?

Comment: With Record Types you only see the picklist options approved for that type. Potentially users could change the Record Type, but you can hide that from the Page Layout.

Comment: Right, but won't the approval process change the record type, then allowing the current approver access to the 'Status' field and the other options?

Comment: I believe it depends on your approval process and the page layouts.

Comment: Presumably, the Page Layout associated with the 'Approval' Record Type would have the Status field as Read Only ?

Comment: @techtrekker, that makes sense. Would the approval process still be able to edit it despite it being read only? If so, then that could work.

Comment: Yes the approval process is doing it at a native level (workflow) field update, whereas the Read Only is only to prevent the user. However the Approver wouldnt be able to edit the Status field then.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not want to bother with changing record types, you could use a validation rule which prevents the user from picking those values even though he can see them.

Have a hidden checkbox field Pending_Approval__c
The validation rule would prevent the user selecting any others picklist values except the three you intend for them to

```
AND(
NOT(Pending_Approval__c),
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Field__c, 'Step 1'),
ISPICKVAL(Field__c, 'Step 2'),
ISPICKVAL(Field__c, 'Step 3'),
ISPICKVAL(Field__c, 'Approved')
)

)
```

As the initial submission action of the Approval Process, set Pending_Approval__c = true
That will the let the Approval Process update to any of the picklist values
Then as the Final Approval and Rejection actions, use a Field Update to set Pending_Approval__c back to false.

Comment: I like this idea, it directly addresses my need to 'lock' a single field to the users. My only question is, will this lock the field to the approval process, too, or just to the users?

Comment: It could be both, though you'd probably want two separate validation rules.

Comment: How will the validation rule know whether it is a user change or a change made by the approval process?

Comment: So you're saying you need for the approver to be able to edit the Record while it is undergoing approval? Coz it is possible to lock down the Record to everyone but an administrator.